# Storing database information to send in an email

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very new to PHP and MySQL and am a little stuck. I am trying to build a website that users will input information that is put into a database. Another user will then input information on their profile and search for matching results. The output is ‘you have x number of people matching this description’ Up to this point I have been fine.

My question is if I would like to take that information and allow user 2 to send an email through the website to all of the matching users, what would be the best way of storing the matched user’s IDs for later use after user 2 has moved through several pages? Should I be using cookies or set up a second database?

Would really appreciate some input! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use second table since cookies are stored in client side. For table columns you can use search criteria details. And before send email you can query the database and get data according to that criteria and send the mail.